# Sum of floor of rational product

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Given natural numbers $a,b,n$, where $a<b$, $n<b-1$, and $a$ and $b$ coprime,

Find a closed form for the sum:

${\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \left\lfloor k \frac{a}{b} \right\rfloor}$

We know when $n=b-1$ the sum is $\frac{1}{2}(a-1)(b-1)$, but is there a closed form for the sum when $n<b-1$?

(Or, is it provable that no closed form exists?)

Answer (score 0):

The difference between your sum and the sum without "floor" is $$\frac{1}{b} \sum_{k=1}^n k a \mod b,$$ (where I am using $\mod$ for the positive remainder). The sum of the each $b$ consecutive remainders will be $(b-1)/2,$ and you can evaluate the sum of the last $n\mod b$ remainders (though it is a little delicate).

*edit: changed sum index from $i$ to $k$ to match $ka$ being summed*

Comment: This is a helpful observation.  But I still don't see how to go from here to a single expression (without a sum in it).